# Upgrading Windows 8 to 8.1 Pro via Windows Store

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Currently I'm running Windows 8 in Boot Camp (MacBook Pro Retina Mid-2012) and get a free update to Windows 8.1 Pro from Windows Store. My question is...

- Should I change the startup disk to Windows in Boot Camp Control Panel before upgrading to 8.1?
- Can I just download and install it from the store and then just reinstall the Boot Camp Drivers to the newest (5.1.5621).

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would set Windows to be the default boot until the update is finished, to prevent it being interrupted by unexpectedly booting to Mac.
I don't think it would hurt anything if it did, as the Windows install would simply wait until next time *it* was booted.

I would definitely update Bootcamp before Windows, in case there is something about the existing drivers that may prevent you booting/finishing/accessing the Windows install if you did it the other way round.

I would, of course, also have a backup of everything before I started.